# Checking array elements using "if $(element).is(...)"

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

Using jQuery, I'm trying to iterate over form elements on a page and break them down into arrays for each input type.

My code so far isn't meant to cover every possible type, but right now **every element** is pushed to the `buttons` list.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
function buildForm(elem) {
    var formElements = [],
        buttons = [],
        radios = [],
        checkboxes = [],
        selects = [],
        textareas = [],
        texts = [];

    formElements.push($(elem).find('input, textarea, select'));

    $.each(formElements, function(index, el) {
        if ($(el).is('input[type="submit"],input[type="clear"]')) {
            buttons.push($(el));
        } else if ($(el).is('input[type="radio"]')) {
            radios.push($(el));
        } else if ($(el).is('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
            checkboxes.push($(el));
        } else if ($(el).is('select')) {
            selects.push($(el));
        } else if ($(el).is('textarea')) {
            textareas.push($(el));
        } else if ($(el).is('input[type="text"]')) {
            texts.push($(el));
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** And a JSFiddle with HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/jakehamiltonaimia/mLd69mhc/

Any other tips to clean this up are welcomed, but not required. :)

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: show us the html code

Comment: why select them all together only to then split them up, why not just use the correct selector to begin with

Comment: why don't you do `buttons.push(formElements.find('button')`, `radios.push(formElements.find(':radio'))` and so on instead of loop

Comment: also you can use vanilla js - el.type === 'submit' || el.type === 'clear'

Comment: @bipen, if you are doing that, why push them, why not assign them directly?

Comment: The more "code" you provide - HTML form, JavaScript - the easier it will be  for other users to copy and paste your stuff into an online editor like JSFiddle, run it, see what the problem is, and provide you with a solution.  If you don't provide everything relevant, other users will be a lot less likely to do that extra work to provide you with a solution.

Comment: Apologies! Editing now

Comment: Also if you want item in array to have each element instead of one element with jQuery object use `formElements = $(elem).find('input, textarea, select').get();`

Comment: @AndrewKoper Thanks for the tip! Edited. :)

Comment: @jcubic You might be onto something there... I didn't even realize all elements were in a single object. Trying that now. EDIT: Didn't solve every element ending up in the 'buttons' array, but definitely an improvement. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @illogicaljake I am getting more experienced with SO.  That's why all of the posters are just providing you with little comments and no one is providing you with fixed code: it will take too many minutes for people to make a simple, dummy HTML form and run your broken JavaScript against it to diagnose the problem.

Comment: try `buttons.push(el);` to have dom node instead of jQuery object https://jsfiddle.net/mLd69mhc/1/ you can get jQuery object out of it using `$(buttons)`

Comment: @illogicaljake I have no idea what your are trying to do here with the arrays. But I think you need this.. Here you go try this out https://jsfiddle.net/bipen/mLd69mhc/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the point in selecting all the elements just to loop through them and split them off

```js
function buildForm(elem) {
    var element = $(elem),
        buttons = element.find('button[type="submit"],button[type="clear"]'),
        radios = element.find('input[type="radio"]'),
        checkboxes = element.find('input[type="checkbox"]'),
        selects = element.find('select'),
        textareas = element.find('textarea'),
        texts = element.find('input[type="text"]'),
        allItems = [];
  
  // if you need all items in one array then you can merge them
  $.merge(allItems, buttons);  
  $.merge(allItems, radios);
  $.merge(allItems, checkboxes);
  $.merge(allItems, selects);
  $.merge(allItems, textareas);
  $.merge(allItems, texts);
}

buildForm('.bootstrap-iso');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bootstrap-iso">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <form method="post">
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label " for="name">
       Name
      </label>
      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label requiredField" for="email">
       Email
       <span class="asteriskField">
        *
       </span>
      </label>
      <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label " for="subject">
       Subject
      </label>
      <input class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" type="text"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label " for="message">
       Message
      </label>
      <textarea class="form-control" cols="40" id="message" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label ">
       Check all that apply
      </label>
      <div class=" ">
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
         <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="First Choice"/>
         First Choice
        </label>
       </div>
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
         <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Second Choice"/>
         Second Choice
        </label>
       </div>
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
         <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Third Choice"/>
         Third Choice
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label ">
       Select a Choice
      </label>
      <div class="">
       <div class="radio">
        <label class="radio">
         <input name="radio" type="radio" value="First Choice"/>
         First Choice
        </label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio">
        <label class="radio">
         <input name="radio" type="radio" value="Second Choice"/>
         Second Choice
        </label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio">
        <label class="radio">
         <input name="radio" type="radio" value="Third Choice"/>
         Third Choice
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label " for="select">
       Select a Choice
      </label>
      <select class="select form-control" id="select" name="select">
       <option value="First Choice">
        First Choice
       </option>
       <option value="Second Choice">
        Second Choice
       </option>
       <option value="Third Choice">
        Third Choice
       </option>
      </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div>
       <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">
        Submit
       </button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function buildForm(elem) {
    var mycontrols={};

    formElements.push($(elem).find('input, textarea, select'));

    $.each(formElements, function(index, el) {
        var mytype=$(el).attr('type');
        if (!mycontrols.hasOwnProperty(mytype){
            mycontrols[mytype]=[];
        }
        mycontrols[mytype].push($(el));
    });

    //do something with mycontrols, which will have 
    //properties corresponding to all the control types 
    //in the formElements collection
}
```

or to get only the elements that you wanted in your buttons list

```
function buildForm(elem) {
    var mybuttons=[];

    formElements.push($(elem).find('input, textarea, select'));

    $.each(formElements, function(index, el) {
        var mytype=$(el).attr('type');
        if (mytype==='button' || mytype==='submit' || mytype==='clear'){
           mybuttons.push($(el));
    });

    //do something with mybuttons   
}
```